# Customized range input passing to default on Blazor

Tags: blazor

Im trying to do a range input with 2 handlers and I found a javascript and css file for it, the problem is when I run the project the customized range input appears and after 1 second it pass to default. You can see this problem in this [Github repository](https://github.com/AdrianoFSilva1/RangeFilter) by running the project and paying  attention in the range input and refreshing the page.

It was supposted showing this range input:

[image: RangeInput]

But what happens, as I said, is that it shows in the first milliseconds, when you run the project, and after that it pass to the default.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="range" multiple value="0,100" />
```

CSS Code:

```
@supports (--css: variables) {
    input[type="range"].multirange {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

        input[type="range"].multirange.original {
            position: absolute;
        }

            input[type="range"].multirange.original::-webkit-slider-thumb {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 2;
            }

            input[type="range"].multirange.original::-moz-range-thumb {
                transform: scale(1); /* FF doesn't apply position it seems */
                z-index: 1;
            }

        input[type="range"].multirange::-moz-range-track {
            border-color: transparent; /* needed to switch FF to "styleable" control */
        }

        input[type="range"].multirange.ghost {
            position: relative;
            background: var(--track-background);
            --track-background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent var(--low), var(--range-color) 0, var(--range-color) var(--high), transparent 0 ) no-repeat 0 45% / 100% 40%;
            --range-color: hsl(190, 80%, 40%);
        }

            input[type="range"].multirange.ghost::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
                background: var(--track-background);
            }

            input[type="range"].multirange.ghost::-moz-range-track {
                background: var(--track-background);
            }
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var supportsMultiple = self.HTMLInputElement && "valueLow" in HTMLInputElement.prototype;

    var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value");

    var multirange = function (input) {
        if (supportsMultiple || input.classList.contains("multirange")) {
            return;
        }

        var value = input.getAttribute("value");
        var values = value === null ? [] : value.split(",");
        var min = +(input.min || 0);
        var max = +(input.max || 100);
        var ghost = input.cloneNode();

        input.classList.add("multirange", "original");
        ghost.classList.add("multirange", "ghost");

        input.value = values[0] || min + (max - min) / 2;
        ghost.value = values[1] || min + (max - min) / 2;

        input.parentNode.insertBefore(ghost, input.nextSibling);

        Object.defineProperty(input, "originalValue", descriptor.get ? descriptor : {
            // Fuck you Safari >:(
            get: function () { return this.value; },
            set: function (v) { this.value = v; }
        });

        Object.defineProperties(input, {
            valueLow: {
                get: function () { return Math.min(this.originalValue, ghost.value); },
                set: function (v) { this.originalValue = v; },
                enumerable: true
            },
            valueHigh: {
                get: function () { return Math.max(this.originalValue, ghost.value); },
                set: function (v) { ghost.value = v; },
                enumerable: true
            }
        });

        if (descriptor.get) {
            // Again, fuck you Safari
            Object.defineProperty(input, "value", {
                get: function () { return this.valueLow + "," + this.valueHigh; },
                set: function (v) {
                    var values = v.split(",");
                    this.valueLow = values[0];
                    this.valueHigh = values[1];
                    update();
                },
                enumerable: true
            });
        }

        if (typeof input.oninput === "function") {
            ghost.oninput = input.oninput.bind(input);
        }

        function update() {
            ghost.style.setProperty("--low", 100 * ((input.valueLow - min) / (max - min)) + 1 + "%");
            ghost.style.setProperty("--high", 100 * ((input.valueHigh - min) / (max - min)) - 1 + "%");
        }

        ghost.addEventListener("mousedown", function passClick(evt) {
            // Are the ghost and input elements inverted? (ghost is lower range)
            var isInverted = input.valueLow == ghost.value;
            // Find the horizontal position that was clicked (as a percentage of the element's width)
            var clickPoint = evt.offsetX / this.offsetWidth;
            // Map the percentage to a value in the range (note, assumes a min value of 0)
            var clickValue = max * clickPoint;

            // Get the distance to both high and low values in the range
            var highDiff = input.valueHigh - clickValue;
            var lowDiff = Math.abs(input.valueLow - clickValue);

            if (isInverted ? highDiff < lowDiff : lowDiff < highDiff) {
                // The low value is closer to the click point than the high value
                // We should update the low value input
                var passEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", evt);
                // Pass a new event to the low "input" element (which is obscured by the
                // higher "ghost" element, and doesn't get mouse events outside the drag handle
                input.dispatchEvent(passEvent);
                // The higher "ghost" element should not respond to this event
                evt.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
        input.addEventListener("input", update);
        ghost.addEventListener("input", update);

        update();
    }

    multirange.init = function () {
        [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=range][multiple]:not(.multirange)")).forEach(multirange);
    }

    if (typeof module === "undefined") {
        self.multirange = multirange;
        if (document.readyState == "loading") {
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", multirange.init);
        }
        else {
            multirange.init();
        }
    } else {
        module.exports = multirange;
    }

})();
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Don't use JavaScript to manipulate Dom elements that are under the control of Blazor.

Comment: What you suggest? @MisterMagoo

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but whatever it is can probably be done directly in HTML/CSS/Blazor without the need for the JavaScript. Blazor components can use JavaScript, but it is usually not needed and should be used carefully as Blazor is not aware of any changes you make to the Dom this way and could easily break whatever you are doing in JS.

Comment: I will update the question and post an image of what Javascript should be doing. What im trying to do is understand why after some milliseconds it pass from the image, that I will post, to the default range input.

Comment: To do something like this in Blazor, you could use the same / similar CSS for the styling, but you would want to create a component with the two inputs in Blazor and bind two values to them for minimum and maximum. This is mostly a CSS problem - getting the two range controls to overlap nicely. Managing the values can be done in Blazor without JS. I'll see if I can knock up a rough prototype component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have taken the CSS supplied and applied it to Blazor without JavaScript.

Below is a proof of concept (needs more work on the CSS - especially around focus outlines) that you could take as a base.

It is slightly different to the supplied JS version as I didn't like the MouseDown handling - it felt hacky.

Use this sample control like this:

```
<RangeControl @bind-ValueHigh="ValueHigh" @bind-ValueLow="ValueLow"></RangeControl>
<span>@ValueLow</span>-<span>@ValueHigh</span>

@code {
    int ValueHigh=75;
    int ValueLow=25;
}
```

Create a RangeControl.razor file and put this in it
Note: The markup/CSS/code are all in one file for the sake of making it easy to post here, in real life you might want to separate some of this (or you might not - with Blazor it's your choice)

```
<div id="rc-@ID">
@(new MarkupString($@"<style>
        #rc-{ID} {{
            position: relative;
            width: {Width}px;
        }}

        #rc-{ID} > input[type='range'] {{            
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 100%;
            --range-color: hsl(190, 80%, 40%);
            background: var(--track-background);
        }}
        #rc-{ID} > input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {{
            border-color: transparent; /* needed to switch FF to 'styleable' control */
        }}
        #rc-{ID} > input[name='low-range'] {{
            position: absolute;
            --track-background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent {100 * (ValueLow - MinValue) / (MaxValue - MinValue) + 1}%, var(--range-color) 0, var(--range-color) {100 * (ValueHigh - MinValue) / (MaxValue - MinValue) - 1}%, transparent 0 ) no-repeat 0 45% / 100% 40%;
        }}
        #rc-{ID} > input[name='low-range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {{
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }}
        #rc-{ID} > input[name='low-range']::-moz-range-thumb {{
                transform: scale(1); /* FF doesn't apply position it seems */
                z-index: 1;
            }}
        #rc-{ID} > input[name='high-range'] {{
            position: relative;
            --track-background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent {100 * (ValueLow - MinValue) / (MaxValue - MinValue) + 1}%, var(--range-color) 0, var(--range-color) {100 * (ValueHigh - MinValue) / (MaxValue - MinValue) - 1}%, transparent 0 ) no-repeat 0 45% / 100% 40%;
            clip-path: polygon({50 * (ValueLow + ValueHigh) / (MaxValue - MinValue) + 1}% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, {50 * (ValueLow + ValueHigh) / (MaxValue - MinValue) + 1}% 100%);
        }}

        #rc-{ID} > input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {{
            background: var(--track-background);
        }}

        #rc-{ID} > input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {{
            background: var(--track-background);
        }}
    </style>"))
    <input name="low-range" type="range" min="@MinValue" max="@MaxValue" @bind="@ValueLow" @bind:event="oninput" />
    <input name="high-range" type="range" min="@MinValue" max="@MaxValue" @bind="@ValueHigh" @bind:event="oninput" />
</div>
@code
{
    int _valueLow = 0;
    int _valueHigh = 100;
    [Parameter] public int Width { get; set; } = 200;
    [Parameter] public int MinValue { get; set; } = 0;
    [Parameter] public int MaxValue { get; set; } = 100;
    [Parameter] public int ValueLow {
        get => Math.Min(_valueLow,_valueHigh);
        set {
            if (_valueLow.Equals(value))
                return;
            _valueLow = value;
            if (_valueLow >= _valueHigh)
            {
                _valueLow = _valueHigh;
                _valueHigh = value;
                ValueHighChanged.InvokeAsync(_valueHigh);
            }
            ValueLowChanged.InvokeAsync(_valueLow);
        }
    }
    [Parameter] public int ValueHigh {
        get => Math.Max(_valueLow,_valueHigh);
        set {
            if (_valueHigh.Equals(value))
                return;
            _valueHigh = value;
            if (_valueLow >= _valueHigh)
            {
                _valueHigh = _valueLow;
                _valueLow = value;
                ValueLowChanged.InvokeAsync(_valueLow);
            }
            ValueHighChanged.InvokeAsync(_valueHigh);
        }
    }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueLowChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> ValueHighChanged { get; set; }
    string ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").Substring(15);
}
```

Comment: Works fine but, Im sorry about this, I tried to do that with a loop, having more than one range input, and I could see that when I move 1 the rest move too, theres a simple solution for that or its too complex?

Comment: It depends on what you actually did in your loop, most likely/common problem is not using a local variable in the loop in place of the loop variable

Comment: I changed the github repository with the loop. Basicly I created a C# file (ExampleList) in Data folder, gived the values for it in the RangeControl Component (on the end of @code) and did the foreach loop. I tried to do the loop in the Index file but same result.

Comment: Your loop wants to be outside the component, so each loop iteration renders a new RangeControl, not inside it

Comment: I already tried it, I update the repository if you want to make sure. The loop is in Index file.

Comment: Now you are binding the same values to every range control. You need a different set of values for each iteration of the loop, otherwise they are all bound together

Comment: Ah ok I get it, I just need instead pass ValueHight and ValueLow pass different variables for each time.